# Why javascript press enter button no function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a text field which is pressable with "enter" button but unfortunately it does not work. I am trying following code inside my project.

This is my JavaScript code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  
    // Live Search
    // On Search Submit and Get Results
    function search() {
        var query_value = $('input#search').val();
        $('b#search-string').html(query_value);
        if(query_value !== ''){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "search.php",
                data: { query: query_value },
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    $("ul#results").html(html);
                }
            });
        }
            return false;    
    }

    $("input#search").live("keyup", function(e) {
        var theSearch = $('#search');
        // Set Timeout
        clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));

        // Set Search String
        var search_string = $(this).val();

        // Do Search
        if (search_string == '') {
            $("ul#results").fadeOut();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeOut();
        }else{
            $("ul#results").fadeIn();
            $('h4#results-text').fadeIn();
            $(this).data('timer', setTimeout(search, 0));
        };
    });

});

    $("#search").on('keyup',function(e){
    var text = document.getElementById("search").value;
    if(text !== ""){
        if (e.which == 13){
            $("#btnSearch").click();
        }
    }   
});

function doSomething(){
    var text = document.getElementById("search").value;
    window.location.assign("search.php?value = " + text);
}
});

</script>
```

This is my HTML code:

```
<input type="text" id="search">
<input type="button" id="btnSearch" onclick="doSomething();" />
```

Comment: is your textbox comes in ajax result?

Comment: Do you have your javascript tag before or after the HTML?

Comment: What you means javascript tag?

Comment: <script> tags....because it seems to be working as expected http://jsfiddle.net/LPnDD/

Comment: @RashminJaviya : I am doing search function inside my code and its work well. I just wanna to addin additional function when I key in value inside in my text field and it will redirect me to a new page which will show relevant result for what I am key in inside my text field.

Comment: @asprin : I want my code to be when I key in value inside text box and I can get return value when I click on "Enter" button

Answer (score 2):

use unique selector id

```
$("#search").on('keyup',function(e){

    if (e.which == 13){
        alert('abc');
    }
});
```

[demo jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/gNLEh/)

use `input type` selector

```
$('input[type=text]').each(function(i,e) {

    $("#"+e.id).on('keyup',function(e){

        if (e.which == 13){
            alert('abc');
        }
    });
});
```

[another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jhyap/gNLEh/2/)

Comment: its work well at jsfiddle but when I dump your code inside my project it cannot work.

Comment: when i press on enter button it did not prompt out alert box/

Comment: do you remove your original `$("input[type=text]").on('keyup',function(event){` code ?

Comment: yap. Actually I used your code before I post on here and its also cannot work.

Comment: remove your `.live` and try my solution to diagnosis the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Place `$("input[type=text]").on...` inside  `$(document).ready` and make sure you are using JQuery version before 1.7 If you wish to use `live`

Comment: I think your answer is the solution

Comment: Verified. the problem came from `.live`

Comment: I have updated my code where it cannot work when I replace "alert('abc')" to "$('#btnSearch').click()". click function cannot work. Hope you can give me another solution.

Comment: @user3517652, Place `doSomething` function before `document.ready`

Answer (score 0):

change your html to

```
  <form onsubmit="doSomething();" >
   <input type="text" id="search">
   <input type="submit" id="btnSearch"  />
  </form>
```

while using this you don't have to listen enter key event your doSomething() function will be called automatically on enter press in input field

[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/pozenufe/1/edit)